# How to export data to excel sheets in WinForm C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

Here my code:

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    int colIndex = 1;
    int rowIndex = 1;
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Con.Open();
    cmd.Connection = Con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table1";
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
        colIndex = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            colIndex = colIndex + 1;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowIndex + 1, colIndex] = dr[dc.ColumnName];
        }
    }

    xlApp.Visible = true;
    ObjectRelease(xlWorkSheet);
    ObjectRelease(xlWorkBook);
    ObjectRelease(xlApp);
}
```

It exports all data from "Table1" to Sheet1. But I want to export:

Row1 => Sheet1

Row2 => Sheet2

Row3 => Sheet3

...

How I can resolved this?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the code `xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);` It should be getting the first sheet.

If you pull that line of code inside your loop, and change the `1` to `rowIndex`, it should go into consecutive sheets. The only thing I don't know is whether or not you can 'get' sheets that don't exist yet, so you might need to create new sheets.